# Automation of attribution data in print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, attribution

I am trying to automate the addition of attribution data in print composer / layout manager for multiple layers contained in a project (using QGIS 3.16). The aim is to present all attribution data as a string within a text box on the map, preferably separated by a semi colon. As a relative newbie to writing expressions, I have tried everything I could find in other posts.

The following expression almost worked, but when layers containing no attribution data were added to the project the code stopped working. have no idea why.

1. `array_to_string( array_distinct( array_foreach( map_get( item_variables ('map1'),'map_layers'), array_to_string( layer_property( @element,'attribution')))))`

The following two codes returned a blank field with no attribution data.

2. `concat( layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,0),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,1),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,2),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,3),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,4),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,5),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,6),'attribution') || ' ', layer_property( array_get( @map_layer_ids ,7),'attribution'))`
3. `array_to_string( array_filter( array_foreach( @map_layers, layer_property(@element,'attribution')), @element), ',')`

I have been entering attribution data in two locations as shown in the images below. I am now unsure if the expression is incorrect, the expression is incompatible with QGIS 3.16 or I am missing a step.

[image: Attribution entered in layer properties---QGIS server]

[image: Attribution entered in metadata---Access---Rights (attribution or copyright)]

Comment: The first solution you have put works by me QGIS 3.24.0 Tisler; it works even if there are layers without attributions.

Comment: Looks as though there must be an issue elsewhere that is preventing their display. I'll try updating to the next long-term release to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Was the Item ID of your composer map set to 'map1'?  i've noticed using some templates from older versions of QGIS that the Item ID is blank.